# Incorrect results when solving an ODE

Tags: differential-equations

The solving of an ODE problem in version 13 on Windows 10

```
sol = DSolve[{x'[t] == Sqrt[1 - 2 x[t]^2]^2 + x[t]*Sqrt[1 - 2 x[t]^2],
x[0] == 0}, x, t]
```

> `{{x -> Function[{t}, ( 2 (Sqrt[3] Tanh[(Sqrt[3] t)/2] + Tanh[(Sqrt[3] t)/2]^2))/( 3 + 2 Sqrt[3] Tanh[(Sqrt[3] t)/2] +  3 Tanh[(Sqrt[3] t)/2]^2)]}, {x ->  Function[{t}, (2 (Sqrt[3] Tanh[1/2 (Sqrt[3] t - 2 ArcTanh[Sqrt[3]])] +  Tanh[1/2 (Sqrt[3] t - 2 ArcTanh[Sqrt[3]])]^2))/(3 +  2 Sqrt[3] Tanh[1/2 (Sqrt[3] t - 2 ArcTanh[Sqrt[3]])] +  3 Tanh[1/2 (Sqrt[3] t - 2 ArcTanh[Sqrt[3]])]^2)]}}`

brings two solutions and this contradicts the existence and uniqueness
of the solution of [the Cauchy problem](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Cauchy_problem).
The above is not a usual technical bug in Mathematica. A bunch of problems related to that ODE problem appears.
First, the results of

```
Plot[(x'[t] - Sqrt[1 - 2 x[t]^2]^2 - x[t]*Sqrt[1 - 2 x[t]^2]) /. 
sol[[1]], {t, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

and

```
Plot[(x'[t] - Sqrt[1 - 2 x[t]^2]^2 - x[t]*Sqrt[1 - 2 x[t]^2]) /. sol[[2]], {t, 0, 5}]
```

[image]

demonstrate that `sol[[1]]` is not a solution of that ODE at all and `sol[[2]]` is its solution
only on the interval $[0,t_0]$ with $t_0\approx 1.04$.

Second, the command

```
FullSimplify[{x'[t] - Sqrt[1 - 2 x[t]^2]^2 - x[t]*Sqrt[1 - 2 x[t]^2], 
x[0] == 0} /. sol[[2]], Assumptions -> t >= 0 && t <= 1]
```

is running without any response on my comp during more than two hours. Likely an infinite loop
is accomplished here as well as in many, many other commands of Mathematica since the resourses
of my comp are not exhausted (40 - 50 % of its processor and 200 - 350 MB of its ROM).

Third, when numerically solving the problem under consideration by

```
soln = NDSolve[{x'[t] == Sqrt[1 - 2 x[t]^2]^2 + x[t]*Sqrt[1 - 2 x[t]^2], x[0] == 0}, 
x, {t, 0, 5}, MaxSteps -> 10^6];
Plot[Evaluate[x[t] /. soln], {t, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

, one obtains the solution only on the interval  $[0,t_0]$ with $t_0\approx 1.04$.

For comparison, Maple 2022 results in
`x(t) = RootOf(t + Int(-1/(1 - 2*_a^2 + _a*sqrt(-2*_a^2 + 1)), _a = 0 .. _Z))`
for the symbolical solution and the same result as Mathematica for the numeric solution.

I think the above problems are caused by

```
x[1.04] /. sol[[2]]
```

> `0.707105 - 9.74433*10^-20 I`

so `DSolve` and `NDSove` are not able to go over the branch point of `Sqrt[1 - 2 x[t]^2]` at  $t_0\approx 1.04$.

The questions arise: is there a workaround? how to continue the solution for $t \ge t_o$?

Comment: From `Maple` solution: `ContourPlot[
 t - Re[Log[(-1 + x - Sqrt[3] x + Sqrt[
      1 - 2 x^2])/((-2 + Sqrt[3]) (-1 + x + Sqrt[3] x + Sqrt[
        1 - 2 x^2]))]]/Sqrt[3] == 0, {t, -2, 2}, {x, -2, 2}]`.You may  remove `Re` from equation give the same solution that gives `NDSolve`.

Comment: @MariuszIwanyuk: Sorry, don't understand you, not being a medium.  Can you elaborate your "From Malpe solution"? TIA.

Comment: Form `Maple`: `dsolve([D(x)(t) = 1 - 2*x(t)^2 + x(t)*sqrt(1 - 2*x(t)^2), x(0) = 0], x(t), implicit)` and solving integral gives: `t - Log[(-1 + x - Sqrt[3] x + Sqrt[
    1 - 2 x^2])/((-2 + Sqrt[3]) (-1 + x + Sqrt[3] x + Sqrt[
      1 - 2 x^2]))]/Sqrt[3] == 0`.

Comment: @MariuszIwanyuk:  In Maple 2022 the result of `int(-1/(1-2*a^2+a*sqrt(-2*a^2+1)) ,a)assuming a^2 < 1/2` is huge and in version 13 of Mathematica `Integrate[-1/(1 - 2*a^2 + a*Sqrt[-2*a^2 + 1]), a, 
 Assumptions -> -2 a^2 + 1 >= 0]` results in `(-Log[1 - (Sqrt[3] a)/(-1 + a + Sqrt[1 - 2 a^2])] + 
 Log[1 + (Sqrt[3] a)/(-1 + a + Sqrt[1 - 2 a^2])])/Sqrt[3]`. Deep regard.

Comment: I'm use: `t + Integrate[-1/(1 - 2 a^2 + a Sqrt[-2 a^2 + 1]), {a, 0, x}, 
  Assumptions -> {x > 0}]`.

Comment: @MariuszIwanyuk: Sorry, you omitted the condition `x < 2/3` in the result of the integration. Deep regard again.

Comment: @MariuszIwanyuk: I also don't see why `ContourPlot[  t - Log[(-1 + x - Sqrt[3] x + Sqrt[       1 - 2 x^2])/((-2 + Sqrt[3]) (-1 + x + Sqrt[3] x + Sqrt[         1 - 2 x^2]))]/Sqrt[3] == 0, {t, -2, 2}, {x, -2, 2}` produces "the same solution that gives `NDSolve`".

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk  should not the solution exist inside a thin strip bounded by $x=\pm \frac{1}{4}$? This is because looking at the RHS of the ode, and taking derivative w.r.t $x$, it is undefined at $x^2=1/2$. Since initial conditions at $x(0)=0$, then a unique solution exist somewhere inside this strip, including the origin, and up to $ x=\pm\frac{1}{4}$. so the assumption should be $x<1/4$. Or did I overlook something?

Comment: @Nasser: Can you elaborate "Since initial conditions at $x(0)=0$, then a unique solution exist up to $x=\pm \frac 1 4$"? I don't understand it. TIA.

Comment: I am   applying first order ODE existence and uniqueness theorem. Writing the ode as $x'=F(x,t)$, then $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}$ shows that it becomes undefined at $x^2=\frac{1}{2}$.  And since origin must lie on the solution path, the solution exists in some strip up to $x=\pm \frac{1}{4}$

Comment: @Nasser: Still don't understand you. There is a possibility, that the solution of the problem under consideration may be extended for $t \ge t_0$ in my notation. This does not contradict the  first order ODE existence and uniqueness theorem which gives the sufficient conditions, not the sufficient and necessary ones.

Comment: I am not talking about $t$. There is no restriction on $t$. It can be any value, as long as the corresponding solution $x(t)$ not to exceed $\pm \frac{1}{4}$.  This is the strip. The integral given by Maple uses $x(t)$ as upper limit. Hence the assumption used to solve the integral should have been $x<1/4$ and not $x<2/3$ that is all what I was saying.  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdwE5.png)

Comment: @Nasser: Thank you. The condition `1 - 2 x[t]^2>= 0` implies `RealAbs[x[t]] <= 1/ Sqrt[2]` if I am not mistaken. I dont know why Mathematica produces the condition `x <2/3` for `Integrate[-1/(1 - 2 a^2 + a* Sqrt[-2 a^2 + 1]), {a, 0, x}, 
 Assumptions -> {x > 0}]`. In any case `2/3 < 1/Sqrt[2]`.

Comment: Opps, I've been writing $\pm \frac{1}{4}$ everywhere, when it should be $\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$. Any way, this is what the limit should have been, yes.

Comment: It all seems fairly obvious from the general solution (IC is satisfied for infinitely many values of the integration parameter $C$, and luckily we got a valid one from `DSolve`) and elementary considerations (all real solutions reach $x=1/\sqrt{2}$ in finite time). I think I'd call it a typical `DSolve` technical problem and maybe not even a bug. Better to get a valid solution (`sol[[2]]`) than none at all, imo, since in this case it seems it is difficult, if not impossible, for `DSolve` to prove rigorousy each member of `sol` is a solution.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit2**

Defining a piecewise function according to the result of `ndsol`  (which is equal to analytical solution  xsol = x /. DSolve[{eq, x[0] == 0}, x, t] below 1.04) proofs this to be a valid solution.

```
xn = Function[t, 
  Evaluate[Piecewise[{{xsol[[1]][t] // FullSimplify, 
      0 <= t <= Log[1 + Sqrt[3] + Sqrt[6 + 3 Sqrt[3]]]/Sqrt[3]}}, 
    1/Sqrt[2]]]]

Plot[Evaluate[xn[t]], {t, 0, 3}, PlotRange -> All]

Plot[Evaluate[(Subtract @@ eq) /. x -> xn], {t, 0, 3}, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Thick]
```

[image]

I'm working with the older version "8.0 for Microsoft Windows (32-bit) (December 9, 2010)"

Another way: Splitting x[t] explicitly in real and imaginary part by `x -> (a[#] + I b[#] &)`  Get same results, See below.

You get at least a numerical solution beyond `t == Log[1 + Sqrt[3] + Sqrt[6 + 3 Sqrt[3]]]/Sqrt[3]`  where `x[t] == 1/Sqrt[2]`   if you NDSolve the complexExpanded equation.

```
eq = x'[t] == Sqrt[1 - 2 x[t]^2]^2 + x[t]*Sqrt[1 - 2 x[t]^2];

ceeq = ComplexExpand[eq, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] // Simplify

(*   2 x[t]^2 + Derivative[1][x][t] == 
 1 + (Cos[1/2 ArcTan[1 - 2 x[t]^2, 0]] + 
     I Sin[1/2 ArcTan[1 - 2 x[t]^2, 0]]) x[t] ((1 - 2 x[t]^2)^2)^(1/4)   *)

xsol = x /. 
  Flatten@NDSolve[{ceeq, x[0] == 0}, x, {t, 0, 5}, MaxSteps -> 10^6]

(*   NDSolve::mxst: Maximum number of 1000000 steps reached at the point t == 3.014453178076721`. >>   *)

Plot[{Re@xsol[t], Im@xsol[t]}, {t, 0, 3}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, {Thick, Red}}]
```

[image]

You see, beyond the critical point, solutions remains constant.

Test with leftsided equation confirms this solution.

```
Plot[Evaluate[Through[{Re, Im}[Subtract @@ eq /. x -> xsol]]], {t, 0, 
  3}, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}]
```

**Edit**

```
eq = x'[t] == Sqrt[1 - 2 x[t]^2]^2 + x[t]*Sqrt[1 - 2 x[t]^2]

ff2 = (Subtract @@ eq) /. x -> (a[#] + I b[#] &)

(*   -1 - Sqrt[1 - 2 (a[t] + I b[t])^2] (a[t] + I b[t]) + 
 2 (a[t] + I b[t])^2 + Derivative[1][a][t] + I Derivative[1][b][t]   *)

cere = ComplexExpand[Re@ff2, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] // Simplify

(*   -1 + 2 a[t]^2 - 2 b[t]^2 - 
 a[t] (16 a[t]^2 b[t]^2 + (1 - 2 a[t]^2 + 2 b[t]^2)^2)^(1/4)
   Cos[1/2 ArcTan[1 - 2 a[t]^2 + 2 b[t]^2, -4 a[t] b[t]]] + 
 b[t] (16 a[t]^2 b[t]^2 + (1 - 2 a[t]^2 + 2 b[t]^2)^2)^(1/4)
   Sin[1/2 ArcTan[1 - 2 a[t]^2 + 2 b[t]^2, -4 a[t] b[t]]] + 
 Derivative[1][a][t]   *)

ceim = ComplexExpand[Im@ff2, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] // Simplify

(*   4 a[t] b[t] - 
 b[t] (16 a[t]^2 b[t]^2 + (1 - 2 a[t]^2 + 2 b[t]^2)^2)^(1/4)
   Cos[1/2 ArcTan[1 - 2 a[t]^2 + 2 b[t]^2, -4 a[t] b[t]]] - 
 a[t] (16 a[t]^2 b[t]^2 + (1 - 2 a[t]^2 + 2 b[t]^2)^2)^(1/4)
   Sin[1/2 ArcTan[1 - 2 a[t]^2 + 2 b[t]^2, -4 a[t] b[t]]] + 
 Derivative[1][b][t]   *)

ndsol = NDSolve[{cere == 0, ceim == 0, a[0] == 0, b[0] == 0}, {a, 
   b}, {t, 0, 3}, MaxSteps -> 10^6]

(*   NDSolve::mxst: Maximum number of 1000000 steps reached at the point t == 2.4880047588617566`. >>  *)

Plot[Evaluate[{a[t], b[t]} /. ndsol], {t, 0, 2.48}, PlotRange -> 1, 
 GridLines -> {{Log[1 + Sqrt[3] + Sqrt[6 + 3 Sqrt[3]]]/Sqrt[3]}, {1/
     Sqrt[2]}}, PlotStyle -> Thick]
```

[image]

```
Plot[Evaluate[Re[ff2 /. ndsol]], {t, 0, 2.48}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[Evaluate[Im[ff2 /. ndsol]], {t, 0, 2.48}]
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce it, obtaining an error "NDSolve::ntdv: Cannot solve to find an explicit formula for the derivatives. Consider using the option Method->{"EquationSimplification"->"Residual"}." and the returned input`x /. NDSolve[{I Im[Derivative[1][x][t]] + Re[Derivative[1][x][t]] + 
     2 x[t]^2 == 
    1 + (Cos[1/2 ArcTan[1 - 2 x[t]^2, 0]] + 
        I Sin[1/2 ArcTan[1 - 2 x[t]^2, 0]]) x[t] ((1 - 2 x[t]^2)^2)^(
      1/4), x[0] == 0}, x, {t, 0, 5}, MaxSteps -> 1000000]`. Maybe, this is a session depending result.  Thank you anyway.

Comment: In view of it I have changed my mind, not accepting your answer and cancelling +1.

Comment: Maybe substitute `Re[x'[t]] -> x'[t] - I Im[x'[t]]` in `ceeq`, or `ComplexExpand` only the right side. Also `Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"`, since the solution reaches the equilibrium in finite time.

Comment: What version are you using? Both your original and latest methods produce equations with things like `Re[Derivative[1][a][t]]` in them, at `NDSolve` complains loudly. I'm using V13.0.1. (For example, this is what I get for `ceeq`: ``I Im[Derivative[1][x][t]] + Re[Derivative[1][x][t]] + 2 x[t]^2 == 1 + (Cos[1/2 ArcTan[1 - 2 x[t]^2, 0]] + I Sin[1/2 ArcTan[1 - 2 x[t]^2, 0]]) x[t] ((1 - 2 x[t]^2)^2)^(1/4)``)

Comment: This reproduces `ceeq`: ``ceeq = ComplexExpand[eq /. x' -> xp, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] /. xp -> x' // Simplify`` -- I guess something has changed, and `ComplexExpand` no longer assumes `x'[t]` is real. May be a bug?

Comment: `ceeq = Simplify[ComplexExpand[eq, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}], 
 x'[t] \[Element] Reals]` also works in V13.

Comment: I'm out of Mathematica at the moment so I' ll reply later.

Comment: @MichaelE2, now show all the interim results. Working with version 8.0

Comment: Sorry, cannot reproduce your Edit the `ndsol = NDSolve[{cere == 0, ceim == 0, a[0] == 0, b[0] == 0}, {a, 
   b}, {t, 0, 3}, MaxSteps -> 10^6]` command produces an error "ReplaceAll::reps: {NDSolve[{-1+2 a[<<1>>]^2-2 b[<<1>>]^2-a[t] Plus[<<2>>]^(1/4) Cos[Times[<<2>>]]-Im[(<<1>>^(<<1>>))[<<1>>]]+Re[(a^\[Prime])[t]]+b[t] Plus[<<2>>]^(1/4) Sin[Times[<<2>>]]==0,<<1>>==0,a[0]==0,b[0]==0},{a,b},{t,0,3},MaxSteps->1000000]} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing." and returns the input. The same issue with Edit2.

Comment: Did you get the same interim results for cere and ceim as i got? Use them directly.